# Could VBA interact with flash web?

Tags: html, vba, flash

when manipulating html  we could use "getElementsByTagName" or getElementsByID to interact with webs ,however I would like to interact with  webs based on flash object(such as clicking,passing value) embedded in html,such as the example below

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Transitional//EN">
      <html><head><title></title></head><body topMargin="0" leftMargin="0"    scroll="no"><embed width="100%" height="100%" src="http://XXXXXXXX.swf? A4Key=1cd445b4vwuspbbrgxqod83d&recallUrl=http://XXXXXXXXX" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" fullscreen="yes" /></body></html>
```

It is an object rather than any accessible handler,is it possible for VBA to interact with flash web?

Comment: You're better of looking for a dedicated program or library to achieve this. If one is written for VBA I would be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get very far with this.  VBA and HTML play well together; VBA and Flash do NOT play well together.